# Accessing a enum value with a pointer

Tags: c

I have a structure

```
   struct abc
   {
       struct xyz *ptr1; int *a;
   };

     struct xyz 
     {
         int *b;
        enum __boolean *filter;
     };
```

here
    enum __boolean 
    {
       false = 0; 
       true = 1;
    };

I have declared a pointer to `struct abc *ptr` and have done a malloc,can any one pls tell me how to access the value in the enum, i want to assign the value.

I have done a malloc of all the structure

```
ptr->ptr1->filter = ?
```

how to access the enum, i want to put the value zero there.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you want to use a pointer for the enum? It just seems to overly complicate things. And C have a built-in boolean type now: `_Bool`. Or you could use the [`<stdbool.h>`](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/C_Reference/stdbool.h) header file.

Comment: I'd recommend `bool` from stdbool.h, to make the code as compatible with C++ as possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the struct field `filter` is a pointer to an enum, you need to dereference:

```
*ptr->ptr1->filter = false;
```

This is no different just because `member` is an enum, it would be exactly the same for any other directly assignable ("scalar") type such as `int` or whatever.

You say you want to put the value "zero", but since the type of `filter` is an enumeration, I guess you meant `false`.

Note also that in C99, we have `stdbool.h>` which gives `bool` and `true` and `false`. It's best to use them, and not do an `enum`, if you can.

Answer (score 1):

Given your code, you'd write:

```
*ptr->ptr1->filter = false;
```

However that will only work if you have already `malloc`ed appropriate memory.  You'd almost certainly be better off making `filter` a non-pointer direct member.

Answer (score 0):

```
  #include <stdio.h>
  typedef enum __boolean { false = 0, true = 1 }__boolean;

  typedef struct abc
   {
   struct xyz *ptr1; int *a;
   }abc;

   typedef   struct xyz 
   {
     int *b;
    enum __boolean *filter;
    }xyz;

    int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    // we can also use malloc to allocate memory to pointers
    abc A;  //struct abc variable
    xyz Z; //struct xyz variable
    __boolean b;//enum variable
    
    struct abc *ptr=&A;
    ptr->ptr1=&Z;
    ptr->ptr1->filter=&b;
    ptr->ptr1->filter=false; /*assign value 'false' to enum member 
    filter*/
    printf("%d",ptr->ptr1->filter);/*prints the value of enum member 
    filter(in this case 0)*/

    return(0);
    };
```

Comment: Please include an explanation for the code, and use proper indentation.